# Random Hardware Addresses in Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, privacy, wifi-configuration, windows-10-v1703

In Windows 10 **Anniversary Update** has been introduced the [Random Hardware Addresses](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/dd1d98f6-7253-9b21-2b7e-06aa6063dc9b/how-and-why-to-use-random-hardware-addresses) feature, which allows spoofing MAC-address each time you connect to Wi-Fi in order to complicate the tracing of connected computer.

After fresh installation of the **Creators Update**, I can't find such option. Does anyone know if this feature was deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature does exist in **Creators Update**.
In my case, the problem was with the W-Fi driver. The initial version of driver doesn't support this functionality but once I updated my driver, the feature appears in the settings.

Answer (score 4):

The **Random Hardware Address** feature has not been removed in the Creators Update. 
It can still be found by going to **Start** > **Settings** > **Network & Internet** > **Wi-Fi**

[image]