# Two Windows 11 systems in dual boot setup: when switching between two, I need to reset my router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, operating-systems, windows-11

I have a dual-boot PC setup with two instances of Windows 11 Pro on separate SSDs.

Whenever I switch between OS's (for games/surfing and software development, respectively) I always am informed by Windows that my [cabled] network connection cannot be established.

I have tried "troubleshoot" on the "ethernet public Network", or ipconfig/renew from command line, and they don't work. I always end up resorting to rebooting my Virgin Media router in order to re-establish a connection. Unfortunately it takes 5 minutes. I know in the scheme of things this isn't that long, but it's disruptive (to attached wifi devices).

Can anyone tell me:

1. Why is my second OS always blocked from obtaining a connection? Is the IP address deemed already in use by the first OS? I'm sure this issue only occurs if I have used the other OS the same day.
2. Is there a faster way to re-establish an internet connection? Ideally a command line or a Powershell script I can run. Even a router setting I can change would be better than nothing. I'd even consider changing BIOS settings if need be.

System:
Ryzen 5900X

Asus Rog Strix B550-F

16GB RAM

3 x SSD (2tb, 1tb, 500gb) - 2tb contains Windows 11 for play, 500gb has Windows 11 for work

PC connected by 1Gbit ethernet cable to Virgin Media 100Mbit broadband

Answer (score 0):

idk for sure, but it may be simply that the same MAC address is asking & the 2 hosts are not happy with the 'answer' for the other OS.

I'd suggest to try spoofing the MAC address for one of the OSes, or using Windows' built-in randomiser. See [Random Hardware Addresses in Windows 10 Creators Update](https://superuser.com/questions/1212736/random-hardware-addresses-in-windows-10-creators-update) …may only work for Wifi.

Comment: Apologies for belated reply. I will try this and let you know how it goes.